# use jQuery in meteor?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have to create a meteor app, but what i did was a simple html/jquery/css page- so now i am facing some issues. i created a filter bar which change as per :

```
if($(window).width()<=600){
        $('#small-screen-filter').show();       }
    else {          
       $('#big-screen-filter').show();      }
```

but this is not working so i done :

```
console.log($(window).width());
if($(window).resize()){
console.log($(window).width());
```

i am getting width of screen only once and the resize function is not working..
PLS help..

Comment: resize() needs to be an event, however why not just use CSS for this type of stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the `resize()` function correctly.

You need to pass another function which calls `console.log()` as an argument to `resize()`

Try

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log($(window).width()) 
});
```